# Serilog - Controlling the LogEventLevel conditionally doesn't seem to work

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog in a WPF application (.Net 6.0), and setting up Serilog by code. The task is to conditionally set the MinimumLevel - In our day to day, set it to Debug, and for a production build, set it to Information.

I setup a DefineConstants prop on the project level as so (compiler picks this up just fine):

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
         ...
        <DefineConstants>_SERILOG_INCLUDE_DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and then in the App.Xaml.cs OnStartup:

```
            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
#if _SERILOG_INCLUDE_DEBUG
              .MinimumLevel.Debug()
#else
              .MinimumLevel.Information()
#endif
              .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
              .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Information)
              .Enrich.FromLogContext()
              .WriteTo.File(LogFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, outputTemplate: LogFileOutputTemplate, shared: true)
              .WriteTo.Observers(events => events
                  .Do(evt =>
                  {
                      var sb = new StringBuilder();
                      using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
                      {
                          // format the log output based on the appsettings.json setting
                          logFormatter.Format(evt, writer);
                          _eventAggregator?.GetEvent<LogOutputEvent>().Publish(new Tuple<LogEvent, string>(evt, sb.ToString()));
                      }
                  })
                  .Subscribe()
              )
              .CreateLogger();
```

This seemed to have worked ONCE, and then fails again. Very unpredictably, mostly NOT -- Debug logs appear, even though MinimumLevel.Information() is set.

I also tried to use the LoggingLevelSwitch class, and set the MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(..), but that didn't work either.

Any better ways of doing this?